# Validation loss not moving with MLP in Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, regression, pytorch

Given input features as such, just raw numbers:

```
tensor([0.2153, 0.2190, 0.0685, 0.2127, 0.2145, 0.1260, 0.1480, 0.1483, 0.1489,
        0.1400, 0.1906, 0.1876, 0.1900, 0.1925, 0.0149, 0.1857, 0.1871, 0.2715,
        0.1887, 0.1804, 0.1656, 0.1665, 0.1137, 0.1668, 0.1168, 0.0278, 0.1170,
        0.1189, 0.1163, 0.2337, 0.2319, 0.2315, 0.2325, 0.0519, 0.0594, 0.0603,
        0.0586, 0.0067, 0.0624, 0.2691, 0.0617, 0.2790, 0.2805, 0.2848, 0.2454,
        0.1268, 0.2483, 0.2454, 0.2475], device='cuda:0')
```

And the expected output is a single real number output, e.g.

```
tensor(-34.8500, device='cuda:0')
```

Full code on https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/pytorch-mlp-regression

I've tried creating a simple 2 layer network with:

```
class MLP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size, hidden_size):
        super(MLP, self).__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, inputs, hidden=None, dropout=0.5):
        inputs = F.dropout(inputs, dropout) # Drop-in.
        # First Layer.
        output = F.relu(self.linear(inputs))

        # Matrix manipulation magic.
        batch_size, sequence_len, hidden_size = output.shape
        # Technically, linear layer takes a 2-D matrix as input, so more manipulation...
        output = output.contiguous().view(batch_size * sequence_len, hidden_size)
        # Apply dropout.
        output = F.dropout(output, dropout)

        # Put it through the classifier
        # And reshape it to [batch_size x sequence_len x vocab_size]
        output = self.classifier(output).view(batch_size, sequence_len, -1)

        return output
```

And training as such:

```
# Training routine.
def train(num_epochs, dataloader, valid_dataset, model, criterion, optimizer):
    losses = []
    valid_losses = []
    learning_rates = []
    plt.ion()
    x_valid, y_valid = valid_dataset
    for _e in range(num_epochs):
        for batch in tqdm(dataloader):
            # Zero gradient.
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            #print(batch)
            this_x = torch.tensor(batch['x'].view(len(batch['x']), 1, -1)).to(device)
            this_y = torch.tensor(batch['y'].view(len(batch['y']), 1, 1)).to(device)

            # Feed forward. 
            output = model(this_x)

            prediction, _ = torch.max(output, dim=1)
            loss = criterion(prediction, this_y.view(len(batch['y']), -1))
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            losses.append(torch.sqrt(loss.float()).data)

            with torch.no_grad():
                # Zero gradient.
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                output = model(x_valid.view(len(x_valid), 1, -1))
                prediction, _ = torch.max(output, dim=1)
                loss = criterion(prediction, y_valid.view(len(y_valid), -1))
                valid_losses.append(torch.sqrt(loss.float()).data)

            clear_output(wait=True)
            plt.plot(losses, label='Train')
            plt.plot(valid_losses, label='Valid')
            plt.legend()
            plt.pause(0.05)
```

Tuning several hyperparameters, it looks like the model doesn't train well, the validation loss doesn't move at all e.g.

```
hyperparams = Hyperparams(input_size=train_dataset.x.shape[1], 
                          output_size=1, 
                          hidden_size=150, 
                          loss_func=nn.MSELoss,
                          learning_rate=1e-8, 
                          optimizer=optim.Adam, 
                          batch_size=500)
```

And it's loss curve:

[image]

**Any idea what's wrong with the network?**

**Am I training the regression model with the wrong loss? Or I've just not yet found the right hyperparameters?**

**Or am I validating the model wrongly?**

Comment: Also, asked on https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/validation-loss-not-moving-with-mlp-in-regression/44878

Comment: You can also try out on https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/pytorch-mlp-regression

Comment: Try using SGD. SGD decreases the error without fail, and so will quickly rule out hyper-parameter issues. (That is, if the error increases at any point, hyper parameters aren't the problem). But in all honesty, Adam shouldn't ever produce a graph like that, so I would highly doubt that hyper-parameters are the problem. I would guess based off the graph you've forgot to account for some form of normalisation in testing or you're re-initialising everything, because that looks completely random

Answer (score 2):

From the code you provided, it is tough to say why the validation loss is constant but I see several problems in your code.

1. Why do you validate for each training mini-batch? Instead, you should validate your model after you do the training for one complete epoch (iterating over your full dataset once). So, the skeleton should be like:

```
for _e in range(num_epochs):
    for batch in tqdm(train_dataloader):
        # training code

    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch in tqdm(valid_dataloader):
            # validation code

    # plot your loss values
```

Also, you can plot after each epoch, not after each mini-batch training.

2. Did you check whether the model parameters are getting updated after `optimizer.step()` during training? How many validation examples do you have? Why don't you use mini-batch computation during validation?
3. Why do you do: `optimizer.zero_grad()` during validation? It doesn't make sense because, during validation, you are not going to do anything related to optimization.
4. You should use `model.eval()` during validation to turn off the dropouts. See PyTorch documentation to learn about `.train()` and `.eval()` methods.
5. The learning rate is set to 1e-8, isn't it too small? Why don't you use the default learning rate for Adam (1e-3)?

The following requires some reasoning.

1. Why are you using such a large batch size? What is your training dataset size?
2. You can directly plot the MSELoss, instead of taking the square root.

My suggestion would be: use some existing resources for MLP in PyTorch. Don't do it from scratch if you do not have sufficient knowledge at this point. It would make you suffer a lot.

Comment: For (1), I think it's okay to log, it's just validating since it's cheap and regardless the model's loss doesn't move on the validation set, during or after the epoch.

Comment: For (3), yes, the `optimizer.zero_grad()` is redundant but it has not effect since the next batch, it'll be zero-ed anyways =)

Comment: For (5), I've tried from LR from 1e3 to 1e-20, all doesn't really move the validation much.

Comment: On batch size, regardless of how the batch size changes the validation loss still doesn't move =)

Comment: On plotting, yes, the loss is sum of squares directly, so the assumption usually is that the sum of squares are small numbers so plotting it directly is okay. But since the sum of squares in the regression outputs are real numbers, it can get really huge and we are just looking at the pattern of plot so the scale don't matter much, thus the sqrt.

Comment: Actually, you can try it out on https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/pytorch-mlp-regression =)

Comment: On (2), yes the model parameters did get updated! Otherwise the training loss wouldn't change =)

Comment: On (4), got it, yes I should not apply dropout in validation, let me try again. Thanks!